# A time range on time range ui filter

Tags: gui-design, filter

[image]looking for an intuitive way to create a time range on time range ui filter.
For example: a way to select last monday and this monday so as to compare between these two.

Or all wednesdays for the last one month.

A time range filter wouldn't work here because it just selects one range whereas what i'm looking for is the ability to select one similar parameter and comparing them.

Would appreciate any comments.

*edit:
Added a rough layout of what I have so far with descriptions.

Comment: Is this about time range at all? Or do you want to select multiple days according to an arbitrarily complex filter? Is it always the same weekdays?

Comment: no, I want to select, for example, mondays, and then compare data for mondays for the past 3 months. So its about a filter that allows the user to see time on time data.

Comment: I would suggest that you provide a sketch or design of your solution first, which will allow some critique of the design from the community based on the design requirements.